# Displaying last x rows of query with limit

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I am currently trying to query all values in a table that have a `game_id` less than `1000058` with a `limit` defined. For example, If I set `limit 3`, I would like to get the last 3 rows in ascending order. I am aware that it can be done by setting an offset like `limit 2, 3` but I would need to know beforehand the row number. Let say I don't know the row numbers, How can display the last 3 rows of the `query` in ascending order? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb187a)

Displays the right values but the order is `DESC` instead of `ASC`

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE mature = true AND category_id = 1004 AND game_id < 1000058 ORDER BY game_id DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Displays the right values but I need to know the row number for the offset

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE mature = true AND category_id = 1004 AND game_id < 1000058 ORDER BY game_id LIMIT 2,3;
```

Displays only the first three rows in ascending order

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE mature = true AND category_id = 1004 AND game_id < 1000058 ORDER BY game_id LIMIT 3;
```

Desired result

```
game_id    game_name     cat_id  mature     description                         published_date
-------    ------------  ------  ------     ---------------------------------   --------------
1000055    Battlefield4  1004    1          Published by EA Digital Illusions   2013-01-01  
1000056    Rainbow6      1004    1          Published by EUbisoft               2015-01-01
1000057    Destiny       1004    1          Published by Bungie                 2014-01-01
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could used a nested query - the inner query is ordered in descending order so you can limit the top three games, and then the outer query sorts the results in ascending order:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (SELECT   * 
          FROM     games 
          WHERE    mature = true AND 
                   category_id = 1004 AND 
                   game_id < 1000058 
          ORDER BY game_id DESC
          LIMIT    3) t
ORDER BY game_id ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

i think this is what you looking for my friend:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM games 
    where game_id < 1000058 
      and mature = true 
      and category_id = 1004 
   ORDER BY game_id DESC
   LIMIT 3
) sub

ORDER BY game_id ASC
```

Comment: I think you need the limit statement on the inner query not the outer one.